# Graph API facebook отправить запрос на вступление в группу или сообщество

Tags: facebook-api, join, graph

Необходимо по заданному списку отправлять запросы на вступление в сообщества и группы. Перерыл весь [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) так и не нашол решения проблемы. Буду рад любой помощи.